# Embed a photo on Discord

Tags: javascript, discord, embed

I’m using w3schools spaces for a middle click to open ms calculator (calculator:) joke but I cannot make the embed photo.

I’m tried to search websites to find code but I can’t find any related to Discord API, Instead it appears with a link I want the link to turn into a picture.

My code:`window.location.replace(“calculator:”);`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.